# Run GUI app with systemd before login (after X is started)?

Tags: ubuntu, xorg, vnc, systemd, tigervnc

I'm trying to run TightVNC server on a Ubuntu machine using systemd. The unit file (/etc/systemd/system/tiger.service) looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Tiger VNC server
After=display-manager.service

[Service]
Type=simple
Environment=XAUTHORITY=/home/myusername/.Xauthority
ExecStart=/usr/bin/sudo -H -u myusername bash -c '/usr/bin/x0vncserver -rfbport 5901 -PasswordFile path-to-passwd-file -PollingCycle 30 -AlwaysShared -display :0'
```

I can't connect to the VNC server and `systemctl status tiger.service` returns:

```
Jun 01 03:12:49 ubuntu systemd[1]: Started Tiger VNC server.
Jun 01 03:12:49 ubuntu sudo[958]:     root : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/ ; USER=myusername ; COMMAND=/bin/bash -c /opt/rmm-agent/x0vncserver -rfbport 5901 -PasswordFile /opt/rmm-agent
Jun 01 03:12:49 ubuntu sudo[958]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user myusername by (uid=0)
Jun 01 03:12:49 ubuntu sudo[958]: /usr/bin/x0vncserver: unable to open display ":0"
Jun 01 03:12:49 ubuntu systemd[1]: tiger.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jun 01 03:12:49 ubuntu systemd[1]: tiger.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jun 01 03:12:49 ubuntu systemd[1]: tiger.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

If I start it with `systemctl start tiger.service` from a console everything runs fine, I can connect to the VNC server.

I have tried `Requires=` instead of `After=` and `graphical.target` instead of `display-manager.service`. I get the same `unable to open display ":0"` in all cases.

Comment: `ExecStart=sudo`? You know there is a `User=` setting, right?

Comment: Also, which display manager are you using? (I'm guessing LightDM from Ubuntu)

Comment: I'm using LightDM, yes, but this is supposed to work on other distros too. Currently using Ubuntu for testing because I'm most comfortable with it.

Comment: What is it that you're actually trying to achieve? Creating a terminal server? Or allowing access to your console session?

Answer (score 0):

It might be that there is no XAuthority in your user directory until you have logged in. There's some information on where to look [at the x11vnc documentation site.](http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/faq.html#infaq_display-manager-continuously) The XAuthority only exists for root, in a directory that varies with the display manager and with the Ubuntu version, but there are a few good clues there.

I'm currently trying to get that vnc server to autostart in Kubuntu 16.04, and my authority file is at:

```
/var/run/lightdm/root/:0
```